# Convert values of an entire column in a datafarme pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
         chr start_position        end_position  gene_name
0        Chr       Position                 Ref  Gene_Name
1      chr22       24128945                   G        nan
2      chr19       45867080                   G      ERCC2
3       chr3       52436341                   C       BAP1
4       chr7      151875065                   G      KMT2C
5      chr19        1206633               CGGGT      STK11
```

and I'd like to convert the entire 'end_position' column to contain the values of the 'start_position'+len('end_position'), the results should be:

```
     chr start_position        end_position  gene_name
0        Chr       Position                 Ref  Gene_Name
1      chr22       24128945            24128946       nan
2      chr19       45867080            45867081      ERCC2
3       chr3       52436341            52436342       BAP1
4       chr7      151875065           151875066      KMT2C
5      chr19        1206633             1206638      STK11
```

I have written the below script:

```
patient_vcf_to_df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
patient_vcf_to_df['end_position'] = patient_vcf_to_df['end_position'].map(lambda x: patient_vcf_to_df['start_position'] + len(x))
```

but I got the error:
TypeError: must be str, not int

Anyone knows how can I fix the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first I'd read your CSV in a way that the `0` row would become a header (column names):

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=1)
```

to get the following DF:

```
     Chr   Position    Ref Gene_Name
0  chr22   24128945      G       NaN
1  chr19   45867080      G     ERCC2
2   chr3   52436341      C      BAP1
3   chr7  151875065      G     KMT2C
4  chr19    1206633  CGGGT     STK11
```

as a positive side-effect:

```
In [99]: df.dtypes
Out[99]:
chr          object
position      int64        # <--- NOTE
ref          object
gene_name    object
dtype: object
```

if you want to lower-case your columns:

```
In [97]: df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()

In [98]: df
Out[98]:
     chr   position    ref gene_name
0  chr22   24128945      G       NaN
1  chr19   45867080      G     ERCC2
2   chr3   52436341      C      BAP1
3   chr7  151875065      G     KMT2C
4  chr19    1206633  CGGGT     STK11
```

to make sure that `position` column is of a numeric dtype:

```
df['position'] = pd.to_numeric(df['position'], errors='coerce')
```

and then:

```
In [101]: df['end_position'] = df['position'] + df['ref'].str.len()

In [102]: df
Out[102]:
     chr   position    ref gene_name  end_position
0  chr22   24128945      G       NaN      24128946
1  chr19   45867080      G     ERCC2      45867081
2   chr3   52436341      C      BAP1      52436342
3   chr7  151875065      G     KMT2C     151875066
4  chr19    1206633  CGGGT     STK11       1206638
```

Comment: why I am getting `TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')

`

Comment: @pyd, most probably the `position` column has string (`object`) dtype in your case...

Comment: yea,   how to convert that

Comment: Perfect, this answer covers all the bases. Nice one! By the way, merry Xmas :-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, thank you! :) And Merry Christmass and a Happy New Year ! :-)

Comment: Solved it :) Thanks and happy holiday!

Comment: @Bella, `errors='ignore'` - ignores those values that can't be converted to number, as a result you will have dtype: `object` if there is at least one such value in a column...

Comment: @Bella, glad i could help. Happy holidays! :-)